# E2E online anonymous messaging service

Tags: open-source, web-apps, chat

I am looking for an online service that would allow people to send an anonymous message, with full encryption (the message would not be stored in plain text on the server) to one of the users. Once they start such a conversation, they would get a unique link (e.g. `/conversations/123-123-123-123-123-abc`) which they can access with a password they have set in the first place. On the other side, the user receiving the message can respond and update the conversation in this way.

Ideally, it should be:

- open-source with possibility to self-host it
- allow user sign-up
- allow sending messages from anonymous public users

What services/software like this exist?

Comment: This is actually easy enough to create. I'll see if I get time to create you an example in NodeJS, but I might not have time. Sorry!

Comment: @mrnoob I know, I could create it too. But there should be something like that already I believe.

Comment: @Ionica Bizau Ok, well then I'll keep looking for an app like that, but it seems VERY specific, and an app like that might not exist unless you modify another app.